# Matlab 2016 reads CSV columns as cell arrays

Tags: matlab, csv, compatibility

I am reading my CSV files with [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)

```
data = readtable(f, 'Delimiter', ';')
```

In Matlab 2015 it gives table like this

[image]

and

```
class(data.IsFault)
ans =
double
```

In Matlab 2016 the result is different:

[image]

and

```
K>> class(data.IsFault)
ans =
cell

K>> class(data.IsFault{1})
ans =
char
```

although

```
detectImportOptions(f)
ans = 
  DelimitedTextImportOptions with properties:

...
   Variable Import Properties:   Set types by name with setvartype
                VariableNames: {1×9 cell}
                VariableTypes: {'char'  'datetime'  'double'  'double'  'double'  'double'  'double'  'double'  'double'}
        SelectedVariableNames: {1×9 cell}
```

How to make compatible?

**UPDATE**

Here is an example I put in Gist: https://gist.github.com/dims12/4458d66e2e4a2a4013ccf77b50771fe1

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide the original data?

Comment: this can happen if there is an entry which is not a number. Can you check in a smaller sample (like 3 rows) if it still occurs? also check for trailing empty rows

Comment: @Finn here is gist: https://gist.github.com/dims12/4458d66e2e4a2a4013ccf77b50771fe1

Comment: In the originial data there might be an empty entry? Try `any(cellfun(@isempty, data.IsFault))`

Comment: @SvenKrüger were you able to reproduce problem with example data?

Comment: I guess you could write a function that goes trough  VariableTypes and applies a casting of the data to the type, using eval (yes I know, its terrible)

Comment: Why don't you use `cell2mat()` function to convert it and get rid of the problem?

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar it wont work in 2015 then. I need compatible code.

Comment: @Dims: You can do `if isa(data,'cell'), data = cell2mat(data); end`. Or whatever needs to be done to convert `data` to the same format as you had on 2015.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with your sample data in both Matlab 2014 and 2017...

Comment: So, in 2017 version they changed behaviour back?

Comment: cant reproduce it either. try downloading those files and run them, maybe something changed while uploading. otherwise i fear your have to go for he `cell2mat()` as @MehrdadZandigohar mentioned

Comment: @Dims: I was not able to reproduce your problem with `readtable` and your example data under R2016a. Even it did not result like your data when inserting corrupted lines to the file. Empty lines are ignored and incomplete lines get filled up with `NaN` or `''` for empty slots.